# fermats last theorem for $p=83$

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Prove the first case of fermat's last theorem for the prime $p=83$.
If I let  $\theta =2p+1$ then $\theta$ is $2\times83+1=167$ where $\theta$ is a prime.
Computing their remainders on division by $83$ we get $1^{83}=1\equiv1(\mod {83})$. 
Any number greater than $1$ to the power of $83$ gets to large, is there another method to solve it for numbers $\geq$ 2?. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add an explicit statement of what you are trying to prove?

Comment: Let p be a sophie germaine prime, Prove the first case of fermat's last theorem for the prime p=83. Thats all i was given

Comment: What do you mean by "the first case of fermat's last theorem"? Can you write that mathematically?